# Ruby - Mechanize: Select link by classname and other questions

Tags: ruby, mechanize

At the moment I'm having a look on Mechanize.
I am pretty new to Ruby, so please be patient.

I wrote a little test script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.google.de')
pp page.title
google_form = page.form_with(:name => 'f')
google_form.q = 'test'
page = agent.submit(google_form)
pp page.title

page_links = Array.new
page.links.each do |ll|
  page_links << ll
end
puts page_links.size
```

This works. But `page_links` includes not only the search results. It also includes the google links like Login, Pictures, ...
The result links own a styleclass "1". Is it possible to select only the links with class == 1? How do I achieve this?

Is it possible to modify the "agentalias"? If I own a website, including google analytics or something, what browserclient will I see in ga going with mechanize on my site?

Can I select elements by their ID instead of their name? I tried to use

```
my_form = page.form_with(:id => 'myformid')
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a list of just the search result links by changing your code as follows:

```
page.links.each do |ll|
  cls = ll.attributes.attributes['class']
  page_links << ll if cls && cls.value == 'l'
end
```

For each element `ll` in `page.links`, `ll.attributes` is a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` and `ll.attributes.attributes` is a `Hash` containing the attributes on the link, hence the need for `ll.attributes.attributes` to get at the actual class and the need for the nil check before comparing the value to 'l'

The problem with using `:id` in the criteria to find a form is that it clashes with Ruby's `Object#id` method for returning a Ruby object's internal id. I'm not sure what the work around for this is. You would have no problem selecting the form by some other attribute (e.g. its action.)

Answer (score 4):

in such cases like your I am using Nokogiri DOM search.
Here is your code a little bit rewritten:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.google.de')
pp page.title
google_form = page.form_with(:name => 'f')
google_form.q = 'test'
page = agent.submit(google_form)
pp page.title

page_links = Array.new
#maybe you better use 'h3.r > a.l' here
page.parser.css("a.l").each do |ll|
#page.parser here is Nokogiri::HTML::Document
  page_links << ll
  puts ll.text + "=>" + ll["href"]
end
puts page_links.size
```

Probably this article is a good place to start:
[getting-started-with-nokogiri](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/)
By the way samples in the article also deal with Google search ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selector you are looking for is: 
**`:dom_id`**
 e.g. in your case:
`my_form = page.form_with(:dom_id => 'myformid')`